# How to override already added important element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor tag which has a style with !important, cant remove this !important from the css because its a default style.

I am trying to add my custom style and I should not use the !important. Is there a better way to achieve this with out important.

Here it is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<body class="imp" id="Imp">
<a class="anchor" href="#">Change background</a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    background: black !important;
    color: white;
}

body .anchor{
    background: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eKHFb/7/)

Comment: You can easily do this with the help of jQuery. It will write inline stylesheet which will get preference. Or you can write another css rule for same element with !important and it will take effect surely

Comment: If someone considered it vital enough to mark the **default** style as `!important` you really shouldn't be overriding it in the first place. Otherwise, just remove it...it's your theme...do what you want.

Comment: @Paulie_D: If I have that permissions to do I would have change it.. any way that can be done...?

Comment: @KD : Yes if I use !important it can easily override, but in my scenario I should not use !important thats the challenge...

Comment: Then simply write inline stylesheet or add styles with the help of jQuery and that will work for your.. Secondly if you just want a default stylesheet then you can have that without !important as well.

Comment: @KD Inline styles don't override `!important` styles just by virtue of being inline. You have to mark them as `!important`, too

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

`<a class="anchor" style=" background: blue!important;" href="#">Change background</a>`

In jQuery

`$("a.anchor").attr('style', 'background: blue !important;');`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKHFb/4/)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to override an `!important` css property is to use `!important` yourself. No way around it with pure css, unfortunately:

```
body .anchor{
    background: blue !important;
}
```

Is there some specific reason that you don't want to use it?

---

If you absolutely must not use an `!important` markup, an alternative is to "cheat" in a rather ugly way with a wrapper around the `<a>` content:

```
<body class="imp" id="Imp">
<a class="anchor" href="#"><span style="background:blue;">Change background</span></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Jquery

```
$("a.anchor").attr('style', 'background: blue !important;');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKHFb/5/)